# Every subgroup of the integers has finite index

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

I think that this statement is false, but only in the trivial case. $\{ 0 \}$ is obviously a subgroup of $(\mathbb{Z},+)$ with infinite index.

In the case of a nontrivial subgroup of $(\mathbb{Z},+)$, intuition tells me that these subgroups will have finite index. How should I begin to prove this?

What I know:

Nontrivial subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}$ are of the for $n\mathbb{Z}$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$. These subgroups are infinite cyclic groups.

I read in another [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1471248/does-every-subgroup-of-the-integers-have-finite-index) posted here that I should try use the smallest positive element of $n\mathbb{Z}$ and Euclidean division to explicity describe all of $\mathbb{Z}$, but I'm not sure what that means, precisely.

Comment: In paragraph 2 I believe you mean "finite index".

Comment: The claim is about the *index*, not the *order*.

Comment: Do you know what the quotient $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ is?

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip The groups of integers modulo n, right? My text uses the notation $\mathbb{Z}_n$, which I think is the same thing.

Comment: Hint. Think about modular arithmetic. How many cosets does the subgroup $5\mathbb{Z}$ have?

Comment: @Chris: The index is the number of cosets, which is the size of the quotient $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z=\mathbb Z_n$. This has $n$ elements, so $n\mathbb Z$ has index $n$ in $\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: You want to show that $n\mathbb{Z}$ has finite index in $\mathbb{Z}$ for any $n>0$.  To show this, try to show that any coset $x+n\mathbb{Z}$ is equal to one of the $n$ cosets $n\mathbb{Z}, 1+n\mathbb{Z}, 2+n\mathbb{Z},\dots,(n-1)+n\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 0):

Sketch of the proof: define $f: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}_n$ with $f(x) = [x]$. Now it is on you to prove that $f$ is a well-defined homomorphism onto $\mathbb{Z}_n$. Also prove that $ker(f)$ is isomorphic to $n\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: 1. No need to prove that $f$ is well defined because it is. 2. Actually $\ker f=n\mathbb Z$.